# myapp.FileSystemFileProvider myapp.androidx-startup error

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, google-play-console

I am experiencing a problem with expo, play store and my mobile application. I recently made the build for the android version (so created an aab file), but when I load it I get this error:
Remove conflicts from manifest file before loading the app. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass.FileSystemFileProvider, com.jawsdevelopers.mealpass.androidx-startup.

I found a lot of soliations asking to edit the manifest file but I don't work on separate platforms but on expo. Any ideas?

If I need to upload some file or some code write it to me because I have no idea where to start looking for this error

I wish everyone a good day

Comment: If the error says the issue is in your AndroidManifest, please share it, so that people can either help you find the error or see that the issue is not there. Odds are something edited your AndroidManifest without you realising it.

Comment: Hi Mister_CK, I know the issue and i found some solutions. But the problem is that i dont have any Manifest file because I'm working on expo so the manifest file i generated by expo on the cloud